# Need help constructing Regular expression pattern

Tags: c++, regex

I'm failing to create a pattern for the stl regex_match function and need some help understanding why the pattern I created doesn't work and what would fix it.
I think the regex would have a hit for `dl.boxcloud.com` but it does not.

****still looking for input. I updated the program reflect suggestions. There are two matches when I think should be one.

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

wstring GetBody();
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wsmatch m;
    wstring regex(L"(dl\\.boxcloud\\.com|api-content\\.dropbox\\.com)");
    regex_search(GetBody(), m, wregex(regex));
    printf("%d matches.\n", m.size());

    return 0;
}
wstring GetBody() {
    wstring body(L"ABOUTLinkedIn\r\n\r\nwall of textdl.boxcloud.com/this/file/bitbyte.zip sent you a message.\r\n\r\nDate: 12/04/2012\r\n\r\nSubject: RE: Reference Ask\r\n\r\nOn 12/03/12 2:02 PM, wall of text wrote:\r\n--------------------\r\nRuba,\r\n\r\nI am looking for a n.");
    return body;
}
```

Comment: try different groupings: `(dl\.boxcloud\.com)|(api-content\.dropbox\.com)`

Comment: im pretty sure [`regex_match`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/) checks if your string is a full match for your pattern. Try using [`regex_search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/) instead

Comment: I just pasted the try different groupings suggestion replacing what I had and ran the program. No match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with the code itself. You mistake `m.size()` for the number of matches, when in fact, it is a number of *groups* your regex returns.

The [`std::match_results::size` reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/size/) is not helpful with understanding that:

> Returns the **number of matches and sub-matches** in the match_results object.

There are 2 groups (since you defined a capturing group around the 2 alternatives) and 1 match all in all.

See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/2wpbVr)

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string data("ABOUTLinkedIn\r\n\r\nwall of textdl.boxcloud.com/this/file/bitbyte.zip sent you a message.\r\n\r\nDate: 12/04/2012\r\n\r\nSubject: RE: Reference Ask\r\n\r\nOn 12/03/12 2:02 PM, wall of text wrote:\r\n--------------------\r\nRuba,\r\n\r\nI am looking for a n.");
    std::regex pattern("(dl\\.boxcloud\\.com|api-content\\.dropbox\\.com)");
    std::smatch result;

    while (regex_search(data, result, pattern)) {
        std::cout << "Match: " << result[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Captured text 1: " << result[1] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Size: " << result.size() << std::endl;
        data = result.suffix().str();
    }
}
```

It outputs:

```
Match: dl.boxcloud.com
Captured text 1: dl.boxcloud.com
Size: 2
```

See, the captured text equals the whole match.

To "fix" that,  you may use non-capturing group, or remove grouping at all:

```
std::regex pattern("(?:dl\\.boxcloud\\.com|api-content\\.dropbox\\.com)");
// or
std::regex pattern("dl\\.boxcloud\\.com|api-content\\.dropbox\\.com");
```

Also, consider using raw string literal when declaring a regex (to avoid backslash hell):

```
std::regex pattern(R"(dl\.boxcloud\.com|api-content\.dropbox\.com)");
```

Comment: Just to sum up: `result[0]` and `result[1]` are 2 groups, while `match_results` object (a *match*) is only 1. `result.size()` shows the number of the groups: 0th is always the whole match and the first and subsequent ones are captured texts.

Comment: Thanks for that. The documentation is confusing because for match_results.size() it reads "Return number of matches (public member function)"  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/

Answer (score 2):

You need to add another "\" before each ".". I think that should fix it. You need to use escape character to represent "\" so your regex looks like this

```
wstring regex(L"(dl\\.boxcloud\\.com|api-content\\.dropbox\\.com)");
```

Update:

As @user3494744 also said you have to use

```
std::regex_search
```

instead of

```
std::regex_match.
```

I tested and it works now.

Comment: Correct.  To clarify, the `\.` in the string becomes a single `.` after the compiler processes the escape character.  You needed to escape the actual backslash.  Alternately, you could use [raw strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to represent the regex, eliminating the need for escape characters.

Comment: I just pasted that suggestion replacing what I had and ran the program. No match.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use `regex_match` instead of `regex_search`. To quote from the [manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match):

Note that regex_match will only successfully match a regular expression to an *entire* character sequence, whereas std::regex_search will successfully match subsequences

This fix will give a match, but too many since you also have to replace `\.` by `\\.` as shown before my answer. Otherwise the string "dl*X*boxcloud.com" will also match.

Comment: I just tried regex_search and I still don't have matches. Will you point out what I am doing wrong?

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wsmatch m;
    wstring regex(L"(dl\\.boxcloud\\.com|api-content\\.dropbox\\.com)");
    regex_search(GetBody(),m, wregex(regex));
    for(auto x:m)
        printf("match %S\n", x);
 return 0;
}

Comment: With the double backslash to escape each period, there are too many hits. I think because it sees too many, that is not a match since there is a false positive. In looking at the match results, there is garbage text for the match results. Example:  ﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮୢⶐ괕ᰀ钸q☐q